# Redirect subdomain only to root

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have this website: www.example.com, which in the past would redirect the clients to www.example.com/subdir

Now I updated the whole site, and the subdirectory doesn't exist anymore, and I want the main domain to be the root. The problem is that many clients have cached the url with the subdomain included, so I need a redirection rule to route www.example.com/subdir to www.example.com.

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ $1
```

which works if I enter www.example.com/subdir/ **with the last slash**

but if I access www.example.com/subdir **without last slash** it won't do the job.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^subdir(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

It is important to use `R=301` here so that all clients and search engines eventually move to new URL rather than keep using duplicate URL for the same content (bad SEO).